# Drupal Accessing Views Arguments in my theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a view with 4 arguments. Say: Red, Yellow, Green, Blue.

Lets say I have 4 pages:

http://mysite.com/myview/red
http://mysite.com/myview/yellow
http://mysite.com/myview/green
http://mysite.com/myview/blue

Now if I want the theme to change slightly based on the argument, how could I do that? I want for example the background of the header to change to blue when you select blue.

Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access view arguments from your theme you can use this :

```
$page_view = views_get_page_view(); // for a page display
$arg0 = $page_view->view->args[0]; // get first arg
```

To change theme according to this argument, you can add css class where you want, or load specific stylesheets...etc